# How to add socket into listWidget

Tags: python, sockets, pyqt5, qlistwidget

I need help with adding python's socket object to PyQt5 listWidget.
First of all, I do this thing in threading server

```
client, addr = self.s.accept()
self.clients.append(client)
```

and then in the `QTclass` I'm trying to do this stuff

```
class win(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.server = Server()
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update)

    def clUpdate(self):

        self.ui.ListWidget.addItems(self.server.clients)
```

but when the client is connected to the server I've got this exception

```
TypeError: index 0 has type 'socket' but 'str' is expected
```

so how can I add the socket to listWidget? I want to use it later, for example, to send the message to specific clients from a listWidget

Comment: Use `self.ui.ListWidget.addItems(self.server.clients[:])` and `self.clients.append(str(client))`. 
QListWidget only serves to show strings

Comment: but how to convert string back to socket object? cause I need to use it with my funcs

Comment: You can not, but you could store the string and the socket in a dictionary: `d= {string_or_id_of_socket: socket, ....}` and then `s=d[string_or_id_of_socket]`

Comment: I've already thought about it but it seems to me there may be easier way to do this stuff.

Comment: What you will find are equivalences, maybe working with roles, but after all it is the same. the widgets only serve to show and not to manage, you want to mix the business logic with the GUI and that is not good. bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried dicts and now it works ok

server

```
client, addr = self.s.accept()
self.clients[str(client)] = client
```

QT

```
class win(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.server = Server()
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update)
    def update(self):      
        itemsTextList = [str(self.ui.listWidget.item(i).text())for i in range(self.ui.listWidget.count())] 
        for key in self.server.clients:
            if key not in itemsTextList:
                self.ui.listWidget.addItem(key)
```

Comment: yes, but its much easier to delete client's socket from a list when it is disconnected than to do the same thing with dicts. Thats why I asked if there is the way to do same stuff with list